# How to disable/enable commands using mvvm command pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm used to developing WPF applications by setting up events in xaml and linking to code behind on the MainWindow.  This makes it really easy to enable and disable events as needed.  I've recently been learning MVVM pattern and have developed an application which uses commands to handle events.  The problem with this is I have no idea how to disable an event command.

My specific scenario is this:
I need to disable some filtering events when data is loading or refreshing so that they don't continuously fire... The data is already being bound so no filtering events should be happening.

In the past, I have done it something like this:

```
    listView.SelectionChangedEvent -= new SelectionChangedEvent(event_method);
//Perform actions...
listView.SelectionChangedEvent += new SelectionChangedEvent(event_method);
```

My understanding with MVVM is that I can use RelayCommand or DelegateCommand and pass in a predicate which should disable the command based on a boolean value.  Then I just need to call RaiseCanExecuteCommandChanged() to update the Command after I have changed the boolean value.  However, all of my tests to make this work just plain don't work...

Can anyone post a brief example of how to handle what I have described in MVVM?  All the examples I can find are for enabling/disabling controls such as Button ... I haven't been able to find anything to actually disable a Command from executing...

Comment: why not to check that boolean value when your command is running? can you also show your XAML where you bind your commands and your ViewModel?

Comment: Problem is there are a handful of events that end up triggering off of one another in a chain.  So I need to just shut them all down to prevent that.  I'll post more of my code shortly.  I posted the original question from mobile.

Comment: You need a command implementation that allows you to specify the `CanExecute` aspect, typically a `RelayCommand`.  There are a lot of good examples on the 'Net for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that a command will not be executed if `CanExecute` evaluates to `false`, you can write a decorator:

```
public class LimitExecuteIfCanCommandDecorator : CommandDecoratorBase
{
    public LimitExecuteIfCanCommandDecorator( ICommand command ) : base( command )
    {
    }

    public override void Execute( object parameter )
    {
        if ( CanExecute(parameter) ) // check if it evaluates to true
        {
            base.Execute( parameter );
        }
    }
}

public abstract class CommandDecoratorBase : ICommand
{
    protected CommandDecoratorBase(ICommand command)
    {
        _command = command;
    }

    private readonly ICommand _command;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            _command.CanExecuteChanged += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            _command.CanExecuteChanged -= value;
        }
    }

    public virtual bool CanExecute( object parameter )
    {
        return _command.CanExecute( parameter );
    }

    public virtual void Execute( object parameter )
    {
        _command.Execute( parameter );
    }
}
```

Now use that decorator to wrap all your commands.

Comment: adding that decorator allowed me to see how the CanExecute test was being evaluated and make adjustments base on that, so this solved my issue!  thanks!